# jQuery onClick hide <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't quite figure out why my jQuery isn't removing/hiding a specific div I've looked at several examples and it should work perfectly fine. This is done on jQuery on Drupal 7. Here's the site in which its live on:http://mahonysbeta.scdmarketing.com/

HTML

```
<div id="closingnote">
<div class="xbutton">X</div>
<img class="note" src="/sites/default/files/ClosingNote.png">
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*closing note*/
#closingnote {
    left: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 175px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.xbutton {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 3px 5px 0px; 
    left: 237px; 
    top: 10px;
    color: black;
    border: 1px black solid;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

JS

```
(function ($) {
    $('.xbutton').click(function(){
        $('#closingnote').remove();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Your code works isolated: http://jsfiddle.net/ts4u6/. What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Are you dynamically adding the div by any chance?

Comment: None. No errors, and no the divs are not dynamically added. Both are made to the Drupal html.tpl.php file.

Comment: This is conflict issue... I've tried the same script in your site, just using ```jQuery``` instead of ```$``` and it worked fine.

Comment: So how should the JS appear? 

    'jQuery('.xbutton').click(function(){
        jQuery('#closingnote').remove();
    });'

? @Kazzkiq

Comment: this code works for me. Are you loading the jquery library?

Answer (score 4):

The code you've provided [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/uvtaS/).

If you're dynamically adding your "closingnote" or "xbutton" divider, you'll need to delegate the click event to an ancestor which was created prior to that being added to the page using [jQuery's  `on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```js
$('body').on('click', '.xbutton', function() {
    $('#closingnote').remove();
});
```

If this still doesn't work, one can only conclude that you've either forgotten to include jQuery, have included jQuery *after* your code or are using multiple elements with the same `id`.

Check your browser's [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) to see if any errors are being thrown, and ensure that your `id`s are unique.

Comment: There's no errors being thrown, and the id's are unique. I was having an error with the $ not being recognized, but that was due to not having the wrapper on the function.

I went ahead and added the code in this manner, (function ($) {
    $('body').on('click', '.xbutton', function() {
    $('#closingnote').remove();
});
})(jQuery);

and it still did not function.